# japanese letters are not displaying properly in my page

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat

I am using tomcat 5.5.x version.When deploy my jsp file which contains Japanese letters,getting junk values in the page.Even i have tried to set the parameter URIEncoding="UTF-8" in the server.xml and  added in my jsp file.But still i am facing the same problem.Is there any other way to avoid this problem.

Comment: What's the encoding of jsp source file itself ? Can those Japanese text displayed properly in notepad ?

Comment: when deploying the same jsp on the tomcat 6.x,Japanese characters are displaying properly.

Comment: Did you set specific content type for the page ? like this: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: i have added this "<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>" in my jsp file. Now Japanese characters are displaying properly. I have lot jsp files. is there any other way like any configuration change to do this.

Comment: You can write a Filter and set content_type globally, like this:         filterChain.doFilter(httpRequest, response);
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");

Answer (score 1):

The default encoding used is ISO-8859-1. To use UTF-8 instead, you can write a `javax.servlet.Filter` to set request encodings. Actually, Tomcat already comes with such an example filter. For Tomcat 5.x, you can take a look at:

```
webapps/servlets-examples/WEB-INF/classes/filters/SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java
webapps/jsp-examples/WEB-INF/classes/filters/SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java
```

Better yet, if you use Tomcat 5.5.36 or newer, the filter is already available for use and you  just need to declare it in your web.xml.

Just follow what is explained here: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding